# Does somebody know some FAQ websites based on phpMyFAQ?

Tags: php

Does somebody know some FAQ websites based on phpMyFAQ ?

Thanks
Joseph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here: http://www.phpmyfaq.de/referenzen.php

Answer (score 1):

You can google for [powered by phpMyFAQ](http://www.google.com/search?q=powered+by+phpMyFAQ)

Answer (score 0):

**Ya I think its popular in FAQ CMS**

if click

1. [google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=phpmyfaq)
2. [alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/phpmyfaq.de#)

you can see if one of popular open source based on php.
So i can say most of the people must be using this. As its a popular one.